# How to configure nuclide-ocaml so it will not complain about Unbound module?

Tags: ocaml, nuclide-editor, oasis

I have a very basic project which I set up by means of OASIS. 
I build it with command `ocaml setup.ml -build`

In my project I have 2 files:

- dir.ml -> where I traverse all files in folder
- main.ml -> where I open it to call the method from dir.ml

When I execute `ocaml setup.ml -build` - no errors or problems, it compiles perfectly, works without any issue.

But in Atom, I see Error: 'Unbound module Dir'.
How to configure it that nuclide-ocaml will not complain on that stuff?[image]